# Can install4j be used to build installer for non java application?

Tags: install4j

I would like to know whether anyone has used install4j to build an installer for a non java-based application? I'm looking to select a cross platform installer which has support to build java-based as well as non java-based applications. In the install4j official web site, it's introduced as cross platform installer for java-based applications. But I would like to know whether anyone has tried to build an installer using install4j for a non java-based application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, but keep in mind that the installer needs a JRE to run. You can bundle a JRE with the installer.

The Java-functionality around generating launchers will not be useful to you if you're not distributing a Java application, but most of the installer actions are not tied to Java launchers.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm currently trying to evaluate some cross platform installation software to be used to build some of our java applications as well as non java-based applications. Bundling JRE is not an issue.